# Best Practices: How to best implement Rating-Stars in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to have reusable ratings (typical layout with 5 stars). 
I have found this http://www.thebroth.com/blog/119/css-rating-stars that explains how to display this using css. 
For actually collecting the rating I was thinking of using an image map or maybe simple radio buttons.
I would like to use this on various different models.

How would you do this? 
Shall I create a widget or can I do this with a template?
Actually I was pretty surprised not to find anything on this on the web. Is it that simple, or uncommon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If received some interesting answers on the [django-users mailing list](http://groups.google.ch/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/3ee1b29805cfe122):

by Mike:

> Well you can create a widget, I like a seperate rating model myself.  That
>   collects the value and then adds that to a total and creates a score or
>   average.  The model stores the total votes and the total score, which I divide
>   and get my average, (I do the math in the view).  Adding it to other models
>   with a foreign key relation.  Enforcing that users vote only once is rarely
>   enforced outside of the current session or cookie lifetime.   If you want it
>   persistance, I'm notfgv6gw33TT   sure off the top of my head what is best for
>   this, but would require only registered users vote.
>   Now, you just display the rating form, I would do it as a template inclusion
>   tag and put the tag in my templates.  This tag has the basic submit form, the
>   form it's self is two fields, with a select box (I went simple this way) and a
>   hidden field labeled next that points back to this page, that I can redirect
>   to. When the user submits, in my views to handle the forms action, I just
>   increment the votes and total score and redirect back to the page the vote was
>   taken on.  This is using the traditional submit button, posting the form to a
>   url, returning a full view.
>   If you do something with javascript that illuminates the number of stars for
>   the rating and click on the stars to submit, here you might want to post it as
>   json object using xhr request, update the view and return a json object with
>   the updated rating values, if it's a 200, update the page with the new values
>   after voting (returned with the 200).  If it's a 500, deal with the error,
>   letting the user know, there was a problem voting and reset the stars.
>   This is what I do, or would do in your position, if anyone has a better idea,
>   please speak up.
>   Hope this helps.
>   Mike

by Ethan:

> I actually just did 5-star ratings for a project I'm working on, and have
>   been trying to figure out if I have anything reusable worth releasing as a
>   package (and trying to find the time to figure that out..)  I'll outline
>   what I did and what I used to do it.
>   I used django-ratings[1,2] for the backend and hooked up its RatingField to
>   my rateable models.
>   I like jQuery, so for the frontend I used the jquery-star-rating plugin[3,4]
>   as a base.  It turns a collection of radio buttons into a star widget.  I
>   haven't looked closely at the implementation but I think it's basically
>   using the same CSS technique described in your link.  To get started you
>   just need to include its JS and CSS and add class="star" to the radio
>   buttons in your form.
>   I then just wrote some view code that sends the request data from the radio
>   buttons to django-ratings.  Super simple stuff, just used the django-ratings
>   RatingManager API and handled the exceptions it throws -- I've pasted the
>   snippet from my code at [5].  (I'm using a somewhat old version of
>   django-ratings b/c I haven't had the time to upgrade; it might look a little
>   different now, I'm not sure.)
>   Finally, I wanted two more things:
>   1) If a user has already rated an item and views the "rate this item" form
>   again, the "star widget" should be preset with the user's previous rating,
>   instead of just showing five blank stars.  I realized the easiest way to do
>   this was from the client side: an onload event that simulates the user
>   clicking on the star he already clicked on.  My view and template code for
>   that is at [6]; I just figured out the HTML formats that jquery-star-rating
>   sets and expects, and clicked on the appropriate star for the user's
>   existing rating.
>   2) When viewing the item, users' ratings should show up as non-interactive
>   stars, instead of as numbers.  I wrote a dumb-as-nails template filter
>   designed to take a number (the rating) and return a bunch of star images.
>   Again, I just used the HTML formatting and CSS classes from
>   jquery-star-rating.  My code for this is at [7].
>   I was thinking it'd be neat to put some of this in a django-form Field that
>   renders the radio buttons and triggers jquery-star-rating all in one go, and
>   handles the submission to the django-ratings backend.  But I haven't had a
>   chance to figure that out yet.
>   Anyway, hope this helps,
>   Ethan
>   [1](http://groups.google.ch/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/3ee1b29805cfe122) http://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings
>   [2] http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ratings
>   [3] http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/
>   [4] http://code.google.com/p/jquery-star-rating-plugin/
>   [5] http://pastebin.ca/1650596
>   [6] http://pastebin.ca/1650609
>   [7] http://pastebin.ca/1650616

Comment: All the referenced pastebin URLs are broken

Answer (score 2):

There is a [django-ratings](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ratings) app on PyPi.  It can give you the rating as a percent 'myinstance.rating.get_percent()' to use in your template for the inner div width in the CSS trick you mentioned.